# Ajax not working propperly on first click

Tags: ajax, modal-dialog

I have this of code that will show the data on a modal when a button click :

```
$("#editItem").on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
            $("#editAlert").attr("class", "d-none");
            $("#editNoChanges").attr("class", "d-none");
            var serialNo = $(e.relatedTarget).data('item-id');
            console.log(serialNo); //Serial Key
            $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="productSerialEdit"]').val(serialNo);
          
            $.ajax({    
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'getItemInfo.php?serialNo='+serialNo,
                data: {
                    serialNo: serialNo
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(edit) {
                    var trig = "edit";
                    var nameEdit = $("#productNameEdit option[value='"+edit[0]+"']").prop('selected', true);
                    var typeEdit = $("#productTypeEdit option[value='"+edit[1]+"']").prop('selected', true);
                    var locEdit = $("#productLocationEdit option[value='"+edit[2]+"']").prop('selected', true);

                    $("#productPriceEdit").attr("value", edit[3]);
                    populateSelect(trig, nameEdit, typeEdit, locEdit);
                    console.log("Editting ..");
                    console.log($(nameEdit).val());
                    console.log($(locEdit).val());
                    console.log($('#productPriceEdit').val());

                }
            });

        });//Edit Funtion End
```

the problem is that, on first click, its not showing the right data, i have to click the button/show the modal 2nd time to show the correct data, what could be the problem or solution for this ?

Comment: Is it showing the wrong data? Is it showing anything? What does the console say? What does the server logs indicate? Is there an error anywhere? Do all the required elements exist? Did you try setting a breakpoint inside both the click handler and the success handler and stepping through code to verify it is doing what it should?

Comment: it is showing the first data on the select option for the first click , the var nameEdit typeEdit, locEdit are shown undefined on the console

Comment: What's the value of `edit`? Set a breakpoint inside `success` handler and inspect `edit`, and also check that the nodes you think exist (i.e. `#productNameEdit option[value=...]`) do in fact exist in the elements panel. While at it, check `serialNo` and make sure it is as it should be (a common problem might be an extra space you didn't notice, for example.)

Comment: edit holds the value for the options and yeah i just checked again, everything is just on their right places and all, it just really like the data is not appearing right away, had to click on the button again for it to show the right data, and not the first item on the options

Comment: edit takes the value from another page with a query and just pass it there with this code     $return = [$itemName, $itemType, $itemLocation, $itemPrice];
echo json_encode($return);

Comment: the dropdown options are the only problem not showing the right data right away, the one text field i have shows the right data on first click